# How to create a SSL connection in PHP with SO_KEEPALIVE?

Tags: php, networking, sockets, ssl

I have some simple PHP code that creates a SSL connection

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->sslPem);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $this->passPhrase);

$this->apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$this->apnsHost.':'.$this->apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

But know how to set SO_KEEPALIVE to true? I've also tried STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified (via network tracing) that you need to set the socket option?

What are you sending over the socket? HTTP/HTTPS introduces its own connection-reuse feature via the "Connection" header, so the option on the socket isn't necessarily what you want to set.

Answer (score 1):

SO_KEEPALIVE like in

> [The SO_KEEPALIVE option causes a packet (called a 'keepalive probe') to be sent to the remote system if a long time (by default, more than 2 hours) passes with no other data being sent or received.](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.7.shtml)

?
I don't know how this is related to STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT but you can set that option with [socket_set_option](http://php.net/socket_set_option) (i.e. using the [sockets extension](http://php.net/book.sockets) and not streams).

Comment: That would be socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1). But then again you don't have the ssl support. I haven't found a way to set the option for the ssl-stream. You would need php_stream_set_option for that, but it's an internal function that isn't exposed to the php script.

Comment: If you find a method to use stream_socket_client() and SO_KEEPALIVE on that stream resource let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->sslPem);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $this->passPhrase);

$this->apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$this->apnsHost.':'.$this->apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$is_keepalive = 0;
// https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-import-stream.php
$socket = socket_import_stream($this->apnsConnection);
if (socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)) {
    $is_keepalive = socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE);
    //echo 'SO_KEEPALIVE: ' . $is_keepalive . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Unable to set option on socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
}

if ($is_keepalive) {
    // https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-export-stream.php
    $this->apnsConnection = socket_export_stream($socket);
}

// TEST
//$socket = socket_import_stream($this->apnsConnection);
//echo 'SO_KEEPALIVE: ' . socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE);
```